# PyGame: Nothing Happens

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am making a game in pygame and when I go to run the game nothing is happening. A black box appears but does nothing at all there is no display etc. Also what bugs me is the fact the Python Shell is not displaying any errors at all. Here is the code for the main file:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import pygame.mixer
import math
from constants import *
from player import *

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        #States (Not country states)
        self.game_state = STATE_INGAME

        #State variables
        #self.stateMenu = 

        #Screen
        size = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        pygame.display.set_caption('WIP')
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        # Player
        self.player = Player(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2)

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        if self.game_state == STATE_INGAME:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            self.player_move()
            self.player.update()
            self.player.render(self.screen)

        clock.tick(100)

    def player_move(self):

        # move player and check for collision at the same time
        self.player.rect.x += self.player.velX
        self.player.rect.y += self.player.velY

Game().run()
```

I have checked the player file many times and there are NO errors in there at all. Well not from what I can see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `while-loop`:

```
def run(self):

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        if self.game_state == STATE_INGAME:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            self.player_move()
            self.player.update()
            self.player.render(self.screen)

        clock.tick(100)
```

Comment: Damnit. Didn't see that. Thank you for pointing this out. Sometimes I just forget parts to add in :/

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. But another issue I am having is my player not moving :( It will display but not move at all. I can provide the code in a private chat for you to look at. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is the player code: https://gist.github.com/GhostFrag1/bd85547df91122bcf1c0 Then the main code is above (Now with while loop of course)

Comment: The initial velocities, `velX` and `velY` are set to zero, and those values never change. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/GhostFrag1/bd85547df91122bcf1c0#). Also, I added [`pygame.display.flip()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

Comment: The Velocities do change when a key is pressed. If you look ib def handle_inputs when a key is pressed velX/Y -/+ 1.

Comment: I don't see a `handle_inputs`. Did you mean `handle_events`? If so, that method is never called.

Comment: I have figured it out! In my main game I dont call def handle_inputs abd as you know it has to be called to work and take effect. Thank you for your help though :)